# Аудит не показывает вопрос, ответ к которому на рассмотрении

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок, аудит

Привет, это снова я, и я [**не** завалил аудит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/72759). Ура-ура!

Хотя этот аудит завалить было бы довольно сложно, поскольку он **странный**:

[image: оценка качества ответа, вопрос не найден]

...довольно сложно оценивать качество ответа на вопрос, *которого больше нет*. А **после принятия решения вопрос показывается**.

Возможно, вопрос в этой ситуации должен быть **показан**, несмотря на то, что он был удалён, чтобы не вызывать подозрений.

---

#### См. также

- Meta StackOverflow

  - [Починено в июле 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265278/2076787) (эм-м?)
  - [Снова наблюдается в августе 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267648/question-not-found-on-audit-possible-bug)

Comment: Какая жалость, когда (если) я наберу 10к репутации, я перестану попадать в такие комичные случаи.

Comment: Неа, удалённый вопрос будет выделен розовым фоном :D